# Array within an Array in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua

If I had code like this in Lua, how would I call 'this'?

```
array = { this = { pic="hi.png", health=4 } , pos=20 }
```

Edit:

Say for example I have a table of enemies like:

```
enemy = {}
enemy[1] = {pic="Ships/enem-01.png", hp=2}
enemy[2] = {pic="Ships/enem-02.png", hp=4}
enemy[3] = {pic="Ships/enem-03.png", hp=3}
enemy[4] = {pic="Ships/enem-04.png", hp=5}
enemy[5] = {pic="Ships/enem-05.png", hp=7}
enemy[6] = {pic="Ships/enem-06.png", hp=9}
enemy[7] = {pic="Ships/enem-07.png", hp=15}
```

I then want to be able to create a table of there positions.

```
level1 = {}
level1[1] = { ent = enemy[2], xpos= 20, ypos=20}
```

how would I call pic, using level1, or wouldn't I?

would I change level1 to be like

```
level1[1] = {ent = 2, xpos=20, ypos=20}
```

then use

```
screen:draw(level[1].xpos, level[1].ypos, enemy[level[1].ent].pic)
```

Comment: I'd call that 'this' a "key" in the table array points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

```
level1[1] = { ent = enemy[2], xpos= 20, ypos=20}
```

> how would I call pic, using level1, or wouldn't I?

You just need to do this:

```
level1[1].ent.pic -- "Ships/enem-02.png"
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that there is no such thing as 'array' in Lua. The only existing complex data structure are 'tables', wich are build using `{ }`

Tables are associative structures, where every data stored can be indexed by keys of any type: numbers, strings or even other tables. The only restriction is the `nil` type.

Let's see an example, we want to build one table with two keys, one number and one string:

```
example = { [1] = "numberkey", ["key"] = "stringkey" }
```

Note that in the example above, the table construction is different from your example.
You index a table using `[ ]`, like the following example:

```
example[1]
example["key"]
```

But this syntax to create and index string keys is quite verbose. So to make our life easier, Lua offers us what it calls a "syntax sugar":

```
example2 = { [1] = "numberkey", key = "stringkey" }
```

The contents of this table is the same as before. But the key "key" was declared differently. We can do that with string keys: put them directly in table constructors. And to index them, we can use another "syntax sugar":

```
example2.key
```

Back to your example, you can access `this`, wich is a string key, using:

```
array.this
```

Sorry about my english, it is not my first (and second) language.

Comment: Aside of nil, you can't use `NaN` as table key either.